# Any difference between those comparisons in python?

Tags: python, comparison, operators, difference

For instance, we hold six variables with paired values.

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
z, x, v = 1, 2, 3
```

Basically, we're using `==` & `and` operators for multiple comparison;

```
In [6]: a == z and b == x and c == v
Out[6]: True
```

But we can do comparison without `and` logical operator, like;

```
In [10]: (a,b,c) == (z,x,v)
Out[10]: True
```

OR

```
In [31]: all([(a == z), (b == x), (c == v)])
Out[31]: True
```

All usages responses as same. But I wonder is there any differences between those comparison methods, say, logical, operational, different responses with different types of values etc..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will all produce the same result (assuming no exceptions are thrown either while computing the values or comparing them).

But they compute differently.  This one will stop if it finds an unequal pair, so not all pairs will be compared:

```
a == z and b == x and c == v
```

If the values being compared are actually function calls, then the functions won't be called if they aren't needed for the final result.

The other two forms will perform all the computations, because you are building tuples and lists of the values:

```
(a,b,c) == (z,x,v)                       # makes two tuples of values
all([(a == z), (b == x), (c == v)])      # makes a list of values
```

Comment: There is a difference between `(a,b,c) == (z,x,v)` and `all([(a == z), (b == x), (c == v)])`. The first one short-circuits the comparison whereas the second one perfoms all of them. In order for the second one to short-circuit, one could use a generator expression: `all(((a == z), (b == x), (c == v)))` (that would most likely be slower for just 3 elements, though).

Comment: True: the tuple version computes all the values, but will short-circuit the comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, there're logical differences between the three given comparison methods. Although I would prefer the first method, I think it is clearer to understand. However, there might still be some execution time differences due to the fact, that different casts have to be called.

So I had a look at the time differences:

```
import time

a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
z, x, v = 1, 2, 3

iterations = 1000000

start = time.time()
for i in range(iterations):
  a == z and b == x and c == v
end = time.time()
print end - start


start = time.time()
for i in range(iterations):
  (a,b,c)==(z,x,v)
end = time.time()
print end - start


start = time.time()
for i in range(iterations):
  all([(a==z), (b==x), (c==v)])
end = time.time()
print end - start
```

Output:

```
0.268415212631
0.283325195312
0.413020133972
```

so basically the first method is the fastest one. Which one may easily imagine, since no "casting overhad" must be performed.

Comment: The right way to time an code snippet in Python is to use the `timeit` module https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#module-timeit

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but in general it does not make a big difference